# Java generics list as a parmeter

Tags: java, list, generics

Following the PECS principle I understand that I can declare a list that I can put value of type T into, like this (T is a String here):

```
List<? super Object> myList = ....;
String object = "";
myList.add(object);
```

Following the same principle, anyone who wants to traverse a list that contains T's might do it this way:

```
void myTraversingMethod(List<? extends Object> anyList) {
  for (Object o: anyList) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But how do I pass the list I produced in step 1 to the method in step 2?

```
myTraversingMethod(myList) <--- Not possible
```

Even if I wanted to I can't seem to even cast the parameter correctly.

Generics experts, help me out here :-)

Comment: what is your error? is it a compilation error? put it in the question, please.

Comment: BTW <? extends Object> is not very informative, because anything extends Object. The power of generics begins when you actually use generic types, say `public class<T> Foo { public T getFoo() { ... } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets clear few things first,
not `List<? super Object) myList`, you have `)` character instead `>`
another thing is list does not have defined method `put`, to add things to list you are using `add`

after sorting out yhose issues everything is working fine, have a look at [this example](http://ideone.com/Co0rMj)

Comment: Sorry about the syntax errors, I didn't really mean for the sample code to be compilable only to illustrate the problem conceptually. Thanks for the example, but it only solves half of my problem. I have these items that i want to put in the list: class Thing<T> { T value; T getValue(); setValue(T t) {...}} And then I have to put these objects into a list that I can pass to another method which then traverses the objects.

Comment: @user1283068 so you have something like that http://ideone.com/7UIwAb right? what is your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the example - kind of silly isn't it :-) I was actually in a situation where neither the "super" or "extends" seemed to fit the purpose, and wanted to ask a question about that. But I was not very careful in expressing the problem and so how could you or anyone else be expected to provide a meaningful answer. Thanks for trying though .. :-)